# Какой паттерн можно применить, если есть одни и те же проверки на одни и те же методы?

Tags: php, laravel

Каждый раз при написании нового продукта, я вызываю одни и те же методы из общего класса, и ставлю на них одни и те же проверки, и так каждый раз, вот пример:

```
     $setClient = $this->setClient($data);
        if (is_null($setClient)) {
            return [
                'code' => 422,
                'error' => 'ошибка на методе setClient',
            ];
        }
        $setSubjDocs = $this->setSubjDocs($data);
        if (is_null($setSubjDocs)) {
            return [
                'code' => 422,
                'error' => 'ошибка на методе setSubjDocsToKias',
            ];
        }
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы каждый раз не писать одно и тоже, точнее копипастить, подскажите господа архитекторы))

Comment: Хз паттерн, но проще в setClient, setSubjDocs и других методах кидать ошибку и обработчиком их отлавливать, вместо кучи подобных проверок

Comment: @InDevX не хотел просто проверки там пихать в основной класс, но в целом согласен, спасибо)

Comment: Ну, это нормально если, условно, is_null($client) то бросать exception. Тем более в laravel все эти ошибки ловятся в отдельном обработчике

Comment: Посмотрите `laravel gate`.